# Date format in JSON view formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, view, json, date, column-formatting

I'm formatting the view of a large list in SharePoint. One of the many columns is a date column.

I'm using the following code:

```
{
"elmType": "span",
"txtContent": "[$Date]",
"style": {"display": "=if([$Date] == '', 'none', 'block')", "padding-left": "3px"}
}
```

As a result I get the date along with the hour, for example: "16/11/1988 00:00". I only want to see the date, without "00:00".

Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use [`toLocaleDateString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#operators) like this:

```
{
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "span",
    "txtContent": "=toLocaleDateString([$Date])",
    "style": {
      "display": "=if([$Date] == '', 'none', 'block')",
      "padding-left": "3px"
    }
  }
}
```

When the user is in the US, for instance, the above format will look similar to **8/26/2020**

---

If you need more control you could also use the `getDate`, `getMonth`, and/or the `getYear` operators. For instance, to just show the shortened month and day you could do this:

```
{
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "span",
    "txtContent": "=if(getMonth([$Date])==0,'Jan',if(getMonth([$Date])==1,'Feb',if(getMonth([$Date])==2,'Mar',if(getMonth([$Date])==3,'Apr',if(getMonth([$Date])==4,'May',if(getMonth([$Date])==5,'Jun',if(getMonth([$Date])==6,'Jul',if(getMonth([$Date])==7,'Aug',if(getMonth([$Date])==8,'Sept',if(getMonth([$Date])==9,'Oct',if(getMonth([$Date])==10,'Nov','Dec'))))))))))) + ' ' + getDate([$Date])",
    "style": {
      "display": "=if([$Date] == '', 'none', 'block')",
      "padding-left": "3px"
    }
  }
}
```

This will result in values like **Aug 26** regardless of the user's location.

You can find more samples of using dates in formatting here: https://aka.ms/list-formatting

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

currently only below options can be used for formatting Date-Time value

- toLocaleString()
- toLocaleDateString()
- toLocaleTimeString()

So your code to format date will be as below

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": {
        "operator": "toLocaleDateString()",
        "operands" : ["@currentField"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,

However, I am formatting a whole view and not one single column, so I can't use "@currentField". I have to refer to the column [$Date].

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you could try following code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "display": "=if([$Date] == '', 'none', 'block')",
    "padding-left": "3px"
  }
}
```